# knowrob_cad_models: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [iai_cad_downloader]

Tags: ros, installation, knowrob, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I installed "Developer setup" of KnowRob in Indigo+Ubuntu14.04.4 LTS, in step

```
rosdep install --ignore-src --from-paths stacks/
```

it shown me this ERROR:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
knowrob_cad_models: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [iai_cad_downloader]
```

How could I get rid of this error? Thanks much in advance for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229300/knowrob_cad_models:-cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Biai_cad_downloader%5D/) by [cui56](https://answers.ros.org/users/26305/cui56/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a ROS pacakge which has not been released into [indigo](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=cad_downloader).

You need to install this [from source](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_cad_tools).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I faced similar kind of problem and one of my great friend helped me out in resolving it. Please, run this

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r
```

I hope that this will resolve your problem. Update me after running this.

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suho0515](https://answers.ros.org/users/40477/suho0515/) on 2019-04-12**:
suprisingly, it solved my problem! i typed 'rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic' before and i add the parameter '-r', rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -r,
so the question is how the parameter -r solve this problem??